# p:menuitem icon customization

Tags: primefaces, icons, menuitem

I want to put a png image file like icon in a menu item.

The code I propose is:

```
<p:menuitem id="lang_en" value="English" icon="sertec-english-icon"
     actionListener="#{langController.countryLocaleCodeChanged('en')}" ajax="false" />
```

The css file is located in: src/main/webapp/resources/css/icons.css

In template.xhtml I add the line:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="icons.css" library="css" />
```

icons.css:

```
.sertec-english-icon {
    background-image: url("resources/icons/eeuu.png") no-repeat !important;
    width:20px;
    height:16px;
}
```

But the menuitem in web page is like :
[image: Menu rendered]

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: resources/icons/eeuu.png, is that path publicly accessible ???

Comment: i think that the icon is only working with  [ui-icon](https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/) in case you want to make it as an image the only solution is to use `<p:commandButton/>` instead of `menuitem`

Comment: what does the console of your navigator show?

Comment: The console doesn't show any particular thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it works for me:

css code:

```
.fa-sertec-spanish-icon {
    background: url("#{resource['icons/espaniol.png']}") no-repeat !important;
    width:20px !important;
        height:16px !important;
}
```

icon location files are like:
rootFolder/src/main/webapp/resources/icons/espaniol.png

and in xtml file:

```
<p:menuitem id="lang_es" value="Español" icon="fa fa-sertec-spanish-icon" actionListener="#{langController.countryLocaleCodeChanged('es')}" ajax="false" />
```

**NOTE:** in css must start with fa otherwise it will doesn't work

Comment: can't you just use the 'class' attribute of the menuite instead of the icon?